# How to add new komavars in .cls to use in .lco?

Tags: koma-script, document-classes, scrlttr2

I want to add `\newkomavar` in my `.cls` file and use it in an `.lco` file.

But it seems the .lco is called before the .cls and it does not work. How can I define new koma variables and use them in an .lco file?

.cls

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{businessletter}[2023-04-20 business letter]

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrlttr2}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{scrlttr2}

\newkomavar[IBAN]{fromiban}
\newkomavar[BIC]{frombic}
```

.lco

```
\ProvidesFile{DonaldDaisy.lco}[2023/04/20]%

\setkomavar{frombank}{Sparkasse Entenhausen}
\setkomavar{fromiban}{DE98~1605~0000~7512~0130~19}
\setkomavar{frombic}{WELADED2PMB}
```

.tex

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,
               DonaldDaisy,
              ]{businessletter}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{Max Mustermann\\Musterstraße 1\\12345 Musterstadt}
        \opening{Hello,}
        \Blindtext
        \closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen}
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can define the new variables in `DonaldDaisy.lco`. BTW: The guides explicitly recommend to load lco-files with `\LoadLetterOption` or `\LoadLetterOptions` instead of `\documentclass`. If you would base your class on `scrletter` instead of `scrlttr2` this would be the only supported version and so you wouldn't have the problem.

Comment: AFAIK also KOMA recommends to declare a CI by writing a lco file. And personal lco files then just should load the CI lco file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `\documentclass` to load `lco`-files is deprecated and results in a warning:

```
Class scrlttr2 Warning: loading of LCO via class option `DonaldDaisy'.
(scrlttr2)              Note: Loading a LCO via class option is deprecated.
(scrlttr2)                    You should use `\LoadLetterOption{DonaldDaisy}'
(scrlttr2)              instead.
```

So you should use:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{businessletter.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{businessletter}[2023-04-20 business letter]

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrlttr2}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{scrlttr2}

\newkomavar[IBAN]{fromiban}
\newkomavar[BIC]{frombic}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{DonaldDaisy.lco}
\ProvidesFile{DonaldDaisy.lco}[2023/04/20]%

\setkomavar{frombank}{Sparkasse Entenhausen}
\setkomavar{fromiban}{DE98~1605~0000~7512~0130~19}
\setkomavar{frombic}{WELADED2PMB}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,
              ]{businessletter}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% not needed since LaTeX 2018/04/01
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\LoadLetterOption{DonaldDaisy}

\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{Max Mustermann\\Musterstraße 1\\12345 Musterstadt}
        \opening{Hello,}
        \Blindtext
        \closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen}
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

instead. I even would recommend to not define new variables in a wrapper class, but in a lco-file or a wrapper package, so that they also could be used with package `scrletter` and therefore also with class `scrletter` which is a wrapper class to `scrartcl` with package `scrletter`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{businessletter.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{businessletter}[2023-04-20 business letter]
\LoadClassWithOptions{scrletter}
\LoadLetterOption{businessletter}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{businessletter.lco}
\ProvidesFile{bussinessletter.lco}[2023-04-20 business letter]
\newkomavar[IBAN]{fromiban}
\newkomavar[BIC]{frombic}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{DonaldDaisy.lco}
\ProvidesFile{DonaldDaisy.lco}[2023/04/20]%

\Ifkomavar{fromiban}{}{\LoadLetterOption{bussinessletter.lco}}
\setkomavar{frombank}{Sparkasse Entenhausen}
\setkomavar{fromiban}{DE98~1605~0000~7512~0130~19}
\setkomavar{frombic}{WELADED2PMB}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{businessletter}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% not needed since LaTeX 2018/04/01
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\LoadLetterOption{DonaldDaisy}

\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{Max Mustermann\\Musterstraße 1\\12345 Musterstadt}
        \opening{Hello,}
        \Blindtext
        \closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen}
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation! What would be the advantage of putting the definitions into an extra `.lco`? It does make things more complicated as you also need to import it in every `.lco`-file...

Comment: `usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` definitely is necessary since I do not get the correct ß otherwise...

Comment: @mrCarnivore I would ask the opposite: Why do you want a wrapper class for something you can solve with a lco file. See also the examples of KOMA in the KOMA-Script wiki, e.g.,  https://github.com/komascript/notepaper-wsu

Comment: If you need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, than your whole TeX distributions is very, very out-dated. As explained in the comment, this is not needed for more than five years! So I also do not know, if your very, very old TeX distribution provides a KOMA-Script version with package and class `scrletter`. Sorry, the oldest version, I've installed, is TeX Live 2018 with LaTeX 2028/10/01 and KOMA-Script 3.26b, which not has `scrletter.cls` but `scrletter.sty`. So I cannot help you with your old LaTeX.

Comment: It does not seem to be this old: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6400 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.10.17)`

Comment: I did use an .lco file for it at first and now thought it would be better to use a .cls instead. Since TeXstudio allows syntax highlighting and easier editing with .cls files but not with .lco files....

Comment: @mrCarnivore The shown date is the date, when the LaTeX format has been build, not the date of the LaTeX kernel. This is shown later in the log file, e.g., `LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1` and `L3 programming layer <2023-03-30>`. I would suggest to update using the MiKTeX console and not only update in user mode, but also in administrator mode.

Comment: Thanks. Only my work PC seems to be affected of this old version. My home PC works fine. I will see how to update the work LaTeX distribution.